# Setting the value in Xib loaded in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to load a `Xib` loaded into a `UIView`, and setting the value to the elements inside the `UIView`. But, I keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value

My Custome View

```
 class WalkThroughView: UIView {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
@IBOutlet weak var walthroughHeader: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var walkThroughInfo: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    //
}

func setLabelInfo(header: String, below: String) {
    walthroughHeader.text = header
    walkThroughInfo.text = below

    walthroughHeader.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    walkThroughInfo.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    walthroughHeader.font = UIFont(name: "BrandonGrotesque-Bold", size: 30)
    walkThroughInfo.font = UIFont(name: "BrandonGrotesque-Light", size: 20)

    walthroughHeader.textAlignment = .Center
    walkThroughInfo.textAlignment = .Center
}

@IBAction func makeMe(sender: AnyObject) {
}

}
```

Initializing it

```
let firstView = WalkThroughView()
firstView.setLabelInfo("HEADER VIEW", below: "Lorem ipsolum, Lorem ipsolum, Lorem ipsolum, Lorem ipsolum, Lorem ipsolum, Lorem ipsolum.")
```

There is no optionals here, so why the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: You need to connect the IBOutlets of your class in the Xib file.

Comment: They all are connected

Comment: Hmmm... can you provide us with the code you're using to load the Xib file and a screenshot of your xib setup?

Answer (score 0):

Views will be loaden from a xib in the viewDidLoad method. Before that time all will be nil, which gave you this errer You have to add the xib as a subview to something first.

Sry for not using comments. Not enouch rep yet...